# String lengths after splitting

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string I would like to split and access the elements as strings. Here is code:

```
x <- "b0.5,0.5"
y <- strsplit(x,',')
str(y)
y[[1]][1]
str(y[[1]][1])
length(y[[1]][1])
z <- y[[1]][1]
length(z)
substr(z,1,1)
substr(z,1,2)
substr(z,1,3)
substr(z,1,4)
```

The length of z is 1, but I can access at least 4 substrings of length 1. Can someone explain this to me?  Thanks!

Comment: can you explain why `length(x)` is 1? You might be coming from a different programming language background where the characters of a string are counted when the length of the string is invoked. This is not the case in R. Here, almost everything is vectorized. Hence length works on the elements in a vector. A string is a vector of length 1. Whatever the size of the sting is,its just 1 string. If you need the size, then use `nchar` to obtain the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Well `strsplit()` returns a *list*, so if you want a character vector of components as a result, then unlist the return value:

```r
x <- "b0.5,0.5"
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
y

[1] "b0.5" "0.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many entries you have my suggestion would be to use `sapply`:

```
x <- "b0.5,0.5"
y <- strsplit(x,',')


sapply(y, \(z) z)

     [,1]  
[1,] "b0.5"
[2,] "0.5"
```